# Enviar y recibir datos con Retrofiten AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, json

Tengo un proyecto que requiere **enviar y recibir datos** de un servidor. Me han recomendado que use *Retrofit*, pero solo he conseguido que envíe los datos al servidor en forma JSON. Para ser sincero, no tengo ni idea de cómo implementar la recepción de datos (recibiría un int y un string en JSON).

retrofit:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final TextView hora  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hora);
                    final int sharehora = Integer.valueOf(hora.getText().toString());
                    final TextView missatge  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                    final String shareMissatge = missatge.getText().toString();
                    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl("http://www.google.com/")
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();
                    CostumBody costumBody = new CostumBody();
                    costumBody.setMsg(shareMissatge);
                    costumBody.setTime(sharehora);
                    giapi service = retrofit.create(giapi.class);
                    service.Calltomyserver(costumBody);

                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("error!", String.valueOf(ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

GIAPI

```
public interface giapi {
    @POST("/")
    Call<Void> Calltomyserver (@Body CostumBody user);
}
```

custumbody

```
public class CostumBody {
    public String msg;
    public int time;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @PauMateu. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No me queda claro cuál es tu pregunta en específico. Quizás te ayude leer [ask] para poder [edit] la pregunta y consultar sobre algo concreto.

Comment: Mirate este tutorial, quizas te ayude
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/10/retrofit-android-app-medica/

Answer (score 0):

Con el fin de avanzar en tu pregunta, la interface entiendo que no está manejando la respuesta porque falta un `Callback` justamente que lo reciba.

Este seria un ejemplo

```
public interface giapi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/endpointQueDevuelvaJSON")
    public void getMisDatos(@Field("time") 
int time, Callback<CostumBody> response);
}
```

En este caso estoy enviando el campo `time`, pero no me queda claro si tu necesitas hacerlo o el `json` resuelve que devolverte de otra forma (para no enviar siempre lo mismo me refiero.

En cualquier caso lo que importa es `CallBack`. Me fijaría en el monitor si devuelve ok el `json` antes de seguir adelante al `MainActivity`.

Aclaro que al menos esto es como lo hago yo, no se si hay otra forma mejor pero utilizo `retrofit` sin problemas de esta forma.